# Importing multiple images using filepath based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import multiple images based on filepath present in a "C" column. Jpeg Files are in a folder name "FolderOf_Images" and Upon running the code it does nothing and also no error was thrown. Surprisingly it worked only once and all pictures were imported in "D" column.
Image files will be placed in D Column. The source code I have tried is below without success.

[Google driver Excel File Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SUmPX_V36i8kkv2VDpQEMVpwKtFwtwtr/view?usp=sharing)

```
Sub InsertPicsIntoExcel()
'Pictures saved with file
'Set column width (ie, pic width) before running macro
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Range, Shrink As Long
Dim shp As Shape
Shrink = 0 'Provides negative offset from cell borders when > 0

On Error Resume Next
''''Delete existing shapes/pictures
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    shp.Delete
Next shp
ActiveSheet.Rows.AutoFit

''''Insert shapes/pictures
For Each r In Range("C1:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If r.Value <> "" Then
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=r.Value, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=Cells(r.Row, "D").Left + Shrink, _
        Top:=Cells(r.Row, "D").Top + Shrink, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
        With shp
            
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = Columns(2).Width - (2 * Shrink)
            Rows(r.Row).RowHeight = .Height + (2 * Shrink)
        End With
    End If
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MoveAndSizeWithCells

MsgBox ("Images Import Complete.")
End Sub



Sub MoveAndSizeWithCells()
    Dim xPic As Picture
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        xPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: Excel sheet image]

Comment: And debugging your code didn't help?

Comment: No errors were thrown because you told it not to.  Remove `On Error Resume Next` in each sub and you will see the errors.

Comment: yes I have removed . now it throws Run-time error 1004, Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: On which line do you receive the error?

Comment: You have not given your filename a complete address.  Something like `"c:\folderof_images\Pict1.jpeg"` would work.  Otherwise it doesn't know where to look.  Give the full pathname.

Comment: Line 22 gives error Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=r.Value, linktofile:=msoFalse, ....

Comment: Using absolute path doesn't help.

Comment: Your filename is the issue.  I ran it with a correct filename and the code worked fine.  Check your path and filename to make sure it exists and there are no unwanted spaces or typos.

Comment: File Path was the issue: Line 22 is Changed to        
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & r.Value, linktofile:=msoFalse, _

Now it is working. Thanks Darrel H.